# I have created a base64 image from a d3 chart and need to post it to facebook using client side javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a base64 image from a d3 chart. Now I need to post it to facebook using client side javascript or angular.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook's graph API and its useful to initilize facebook media account with oauth.io.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

```
FB.api(
"/me/photos",
"POST",
{
    "url": "{image-url}"
},
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

Here is a simple code block. But there must be a image size about 1mb or something like that.